# no audio on hdmi tv display

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi

i been trying to set up my vizio hd tv as a monitor for my pc trough hdmi,
i get video not as good as it is on windows 7 but ok i can deal with that is not that bad.
my problem  is that i get no audio, the sound stays in my laptop.

this is a list of things i done to try to fix this issue:

1. ran additional drivers app. to identify my monitor and install the drivers and i 
   get 2 options they are basically the same i believe

   - ATI/AMD PROPRIETARY FGLRX GRAPHICS DRIVER
   - ATI/AMD PROPRIETARY FGLRX GRAPHICS DRIVER (post-release update)

   i couldn't install ATI/AMD PROPRIETARY FGLRX GRAPHICS DRIVER (post-release update)
   due to some error:

   > Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
   >
   > Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

   so i installed the other one.
2. i opened sound settings and i was hoping i could switch my output device but 
   to my surprise the only output device available was the built in device;
   i been looking all over for a solution to this problem. i cant fix it please help.

here is a the results to `lspci` cmd hope you see all the info you need regarding my sound and video card.

```
**PROCESSOR: AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2 
GRAPICS:VESA: DVST
DRIVER: VESA: DVST**


cnc@cnc-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
**00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9990
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9902
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port**
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a0
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a1
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E P
```

jockey.log:

```
2012-07-21 01:41:23,620 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x1062e60>
2012-07-21 01:41:27,137 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/modules.alias
2012-07-21 01:41:27,369 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/b43
2012-07-21 01:41:27,420 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2012-07-21 01:41:27,568 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/madwifi.py
2012-07-21 01:41:27,671 WARNING: modinfo for module ath_pci failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ath_pci

2012-07-21 01:41:27,671 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.MadwifiHandler from name MadwifiHandler
2012-07-21 01:41:27,672 DEBUG: Alternate Atheros "madwifi" driver availability undetermined, adding to pool
2012-07-21 01:41:27,672 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/broadcom_wl.py
2012-07-21 01:41:27,733 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2012-07-21 01:41:27,769 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.BroadcomWLHandler from name BroadcomWLHandler
2012-07-21 01:41:27,769 DEBUG: Broadcom STA wireless driver availability undetermined, adding to pool
2012-07-21 01:41:27,769 DEBUG: loading custom handler /usr/share/jockey/handlers/nvidia.py
2012-07-21 01:41:27,929 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_96 failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_96

2012-07-21 01:41:27,935 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.NvidiaDriver96 from name NvidiaDriver96
2012-07-21 01:41:27,937 DEBUG: nvidia.available: falling back to default
2012-07-21 01:41:28,265 DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(nvidia_96, nvidia-96, None): Disabling as package video ABI xorg-video-abi-10 does not match X.org video ABI xorg-video-abi-11
2012-07-21 01:41:28,265 DEBUG: NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver not available
2012-07-21 01:41:28,270 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_current failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_current

2012-07-21 01:41:28,276 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.NvidiaDriverCurrent from name NvidiaDriverCurrent
2012-07-21 01:41:28,277 DEBUG: nvidia.available: falling back to default
2012-07-21 01:41:28,330 DEBUG: NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver availability undetermined, adding to pool
2012-07-21 01:41:28,338 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_current_updates failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_current_updates

2012-07-21 01:41:28,343 DEBUG: Instantiated Handler subclass __builtin__.NvidiaDriverCurrentUpdates from name NvidiaDriverCurrentUpdates
2012-07-21 01:41:28,344 DEBUG: nvidia.available: falling back to default
2012-07-21 01:41:28,399 DEBUG: NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) availability undetermined, adding to pool
2012-07-21 01:41:28,403 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_173_updates failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_173_updates
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the driver supports HMDi audio at all or on that particular hardware. Could you also post the jocky log? This seems to be rather new hardware, so getting the post release drivers to install might be a good thing and is worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the proprietary AMD graphics driver in the Ubuntu 12.04 [repositories is 8.960](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fglrx-amdcccle-updates). The latest driver on the [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) is currently 12.6 ([8.961](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Catalyst_12.6)) which was released a month ago.

I would recommend uninstalling the old driver and [installing the new driver manually, as described in the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Manually_installing_Catalyst_12.6).